# Generate dataframe series from current series which is a list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{"submissionTime":"2019-02-25T09:26:00","b_data":{"bName":"Masato","b_Acc":[{"id":0,"transactions":[{"date":"2019-12-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-03","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-460.21,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-871.62,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-18","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-498.34,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-29","text":"INTEREST","amount":-794.4,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-484.87,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-882.04,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-21","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-503.59,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-916.98,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-489.65,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-08-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-892.13,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]}]}]}}
```

I am trying to create a dataframe and add a new series in it called category, the value from this series comes from the tags series. The tag series is a list of key value objects

I need to retrieve the category of each row, and if the list of each row doesnt have a category, then the value should be unknown, making the end result of the dataframe to look like this

[image: sample of dataframe]

I havent been able to do much progress, as I dont know how to and what will be the best practice to go through each cell in the tags column

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('question.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
df = pd.json_normalize(d['b_data']['b_Acc'])

frames = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    frames = frames + row['transactions']
df = pd.DataFrame(frames)

df['category'] = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is by creating an auxiliary function to extract the category from your tag and return it when found or 'unknown' otherwise. Then using `.apply()` with that function will do the trick:

```
json_string = '''{"submissionTime":"2019-02-25T09:26:00","b_data":{"bName":"Masato","b_Acc":[{"id":0,"transactions":[{"date":"2019-12-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-03","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-460.21,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-871.62,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-31","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-18","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-12-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-498.34,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-29","text":"INTEREST","amount":-794.4,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-11-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-484.87,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-31","text":"INTEREST","amount":-882.04,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-21","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-10-01","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-503.59,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-916.98,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-30","text":"LOAN SERVICE FEE","amount":-120,"type":"Loan Related Fees","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-19","text":"PERIODICAL PAYMENT","amount":3397,"type":"","tags":[{"institution":"University of MC"},{"lenderType":"private"},{"category":"birdy"},{"creditDebit":"credit"}]},{"date":"2019-09-02","text":"LINE FEE","amount":-489.65,"type":"Overdrawn Fees","tags":[{"category":"Overdrawn"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]},{"date":"2019-08-30","text":"INTEREST","amount":-892.13,"type":"Interest Charge","tags":[{"category":"Fees"},{"creditDebit":"debit"}]}]}]}}'''
js = json.loads(json_string)
df = pd.DataFrame(js['b_data']['b_Acc'][0]['transactions'])

def extract_category(tag):
    dall = {}
    # we create a new unique dict with all the items in the tag
    for d in tag:
        dall.update(d)
    # if category is in our new dict, return it else return unknown
    if 'category' in dall.keys():
        return dall['category']
    else:
        return 'unknown'

df['category'] = df.tags.apply(lambda x: extract_category(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!!, 1 quick question that is off topic, the transaction is a list, in this example is only 1 element, but they could be many, that is why i created the loop: for index, row in df.iterrows(): but i know loop in pandas is not the best practice, is there a way to capture all transactions without using a loop?

Comment: If you mean that the tag elements could be a list of lists instead of a list, you can 'flatten' them out before using for example: `from chain import itertools; tag = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tag))`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: sorry for confusion, I meant the loop that I created after generating the dataframe (for index, row in df.iterrows():
    frames = frames + row['transactions']), I am not sure if that is a good practice to join all the elements in the transactions list